# solve callback hell on class initializer for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery-callback

I am using npm package "**mssql**"
In order to open connection. I have to do:

```
var getOneToken = function (callback) {
    var token = "";

    var connection = new sql.Connection(dbConfig, function(err){   //<-----line 3
        if(err) console.log(err);

        var sqlrequest = new sql.Request(connection);

        sqlrequest.query('select top 1 [accessToken] from AccessToken', function(err, recordset){
            if(err) console.log(err);

            token = recordset[0]['accessToken'];

            connection.close();

            callback(token);
        })
    });
    //how to await the whole block at the top and prevent early execution of code afterwards.
};
```

The code in this block need to be delayed until database return the result, which is the token.
Then further operation can be carried out.

I don't know how to await the code.

Since I tried:

```
connection = await { new sql.Connection(dbConfig, defer (var err)) }
```

It fails. Because **tamejs** don't allow you to put keyword 'await' over there.

I also use **bluebird**, **asyncawait** library, however, it is very hard to flatten the whole block
and 'await' on class initialize especially for line 3.

How to deal with this problem ?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't realise what the problem is. You're getting a token from SQL; what do you want to do then? What specifically is preventing you from doing it? Or is it just the fact you don't understand callbacks and continuation passing style?

Comment: @Amadan I have to use callback to pass 'return value', I found none of the tool can await the block on line 3. Since I always print 'undefined' value after calling this block of code. I am still not familiar with continuation passing style...

Comment: You can't wait. That is not how node works. Give the value to `callback`, like the code is already doing. Forget about `return`. `return` is only useful for things you can give back immediately; if you need to wait, that's what `callback` is for. All the asynchronous libraries (async, await...) are just making synchronization of several callbacks easier, and it does not apply to whatever you are doing. Tamejs is actually not JavaScript. So, again I ask: what is it you would you want to do after the "wait"? "return value" is not an answer, think bigger. What do you want the token for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sqlConnect(dbConfig, cb) {
  var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
  conn.connect(function (err) {
    cb(err, conn);
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
sqlConnect(dbConfig, function (err, conn) {
  // do your stuff here
});
```

Or using tamejs:

```
var err, conn;
await { sqlConnect(dbConfig, defer(err, conn); }
// do your stuff here
```

To layout callbacks, you may also want to take a look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

---

Update: If what you want is only avoid callback chain, you don't need to extract a new function for establishing connection. Instead, you can rewrite your function like this:

```
var getOneToken = function (dbConfig, cb) {
    var err, recordset;
    var token = "";

    var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);

    await { conn.connect(defer(err)); }
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        cb(token);
        return;
    }

    var request = new sql.Request(conn);
    await { request.query('select top 1 [accessToken] from AccessToken', defer(err, recordset)); }
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        token = recordset[0]['accessToken'];
    }

    conn.close();
    cb(token);
};
```

Comment: Your last piece of code use 'defer(err, conn)', But in order to close connection. You have to know the name of connection. Hence, var connection = new sql.Connection(dbConfig, function(err){  ... }. Also if you look at https://www.npmjs.org/package/mssql,  there is no 'conn' on callback.

Comment: @CodeFarmer See the implementation of `sqlConnect`. At first, it new a connection without a callback. So you can get `conn` before connected. Then call `connect` on `conn`, with a lambda callback which only accept a single `err` argument. And the lambda calls `cb(err, conn)`, so that you get `conn` in `cb`.